# Ruby - Hash - Combination

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash with 5 elements, for instance:

```
my_hash = {a: 'qwe', b: 'zcx', c: 'dss', d: 'ccc', e: 'www' }
```

My goal is to return for every time in loop hash but without one element like:

```
my_hash = {a: 'qwe', b: 'zcx', c: 'dss', d: 'ccc' }
```

then

```
my_hash = {a: 'qwe', b: 'zcx', c: 'dss', e: 'www' }
```

and so on

Using array I would use combination method but when I use hash?
I would like to do it as easily as possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert it to an array and convert it back to hash later:

```
my_hash.to_a.combination(4).to_a.sample.to_h
# => {:a=>"qwe", :b=>"zcx", :c=>"dss", :e=>"www"}
my_hash.to_a.combination(4).to_a.sample.to_h
# => {:a=>"qwe", :c=>"dss", :d=>"ccc", :e=>"www"}
```

Comment: Yours is better. A refinement: `my_hash.to_a.combination(4).lazy.map(&:to_h).each` to get OP's loop.

Comment: Why would you want to use lazy enumeration for static data?

Comment: @Glupo: What do you mean, static data? The purpose - to avoid generating the array of hashes. With it, `map` returns an `Enumerator::Lazy`; without it, `map` instantiates an `Array` of the same size as the one produced by `combination`.